# Spring boot creating excel error(The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)]

Tags: java, excel, spring, html, spring-boot

i want to write create an excel and download it but when i add image i get following error.

> [(The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)]

but the file is loaded if i printout its name and path it shows rite name and path

> file NAME: example.png LOCATION file:\D:\blueplustech\plastocartreport\target\plastocartreport-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!\BOOT-INF\classes!\static\example.png

**class:**

```
//FileInputStream obtains input bytes from the image file
    InputStream inputStream = new 
FileInputStream(getClass().getResource("/static/example.png").getFile());
    //Get the contents of an InputStream as a byte[].
    byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
    //Adds a picture to the workbook
    int pictureIdx = workbook.addPicture(bytes, 
Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);
    //close the input stream
    inputStream.close();

    //Returns an object that handles instantiating concrete classes
    CreationHelper helper = workbook.getCreationHelper();

    //Creates the top-level drawing patriarch.
    Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();

    //Create an anchor that is attached to the worksheet
    ClientAnchor anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();
    //set top-left corner for the image
    anchor.setCol1(1);
    anchor.setRow1(2);

    //Creates a picture
    Picture pict = drawing.createPicture(anchor, pictureIdx);
    //Reset the image to the original size
    pict.resize();
```

any suggestions...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use file but getResourceAsStream instead

Instead of the

```
InputStream inputStream = new 
FileInputStream(getClass().getResource("/static/example.png").getFile());
```

use

```
InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/static/example.png");
```

Comment: let me check this .